# Sign of force for assumed $mgy$ gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

If gravity force of earth is $mg$:

1. if positive y is pointing upwards, then: $m\vec a = -mg\hat y$ and
   $\ddot y = -g$
2. if positive y is pointing down, then: $m\vec a = mg\hat y$ and $\ddot y = g$

If you assume force is $mgy$:

3. if positive y is pointing upwards, then: $m\ddot y = -mgy$ and
   $\ddot y = -gy$
4. if positive y is pointing down, then: $m\ddot y = mgy$ and $\ddot y = gy$

Solving the (3) and (4) differential eqs end up having completely different trajectories((3) with $c_1cos(\sqrt{2g}t)$ while (4) with $Ae^{\sqrt{g}t} + Be^{-\sqrt{g}t}$ which shouldn't be the case. There seems to be a flaw in (3) or (4), but no idea what.

Comment: "If you assume force is mgy..." The *force* is *not* $mgy$. The quantity $mgy$ is the gravitational potential energy (or negative of the gravitational potential energy depending on your conventions). The force is $mg$ in magnitude and its direction is towards the earth, regardless of your conventions for which direction of y is positive.

Comment: @user1079505 correct and i know potential is $mgy$, but i am assuming that force is $mgy$.

Comment: In all 4 equations units on the left and right sides disagree.

Comment: Otherwise, there are systems where the force grows linearly with the distance: harmonic oscillators. You may want to learn about them.

Comment: *i know potential is $mgy$, but i am assuming that force is $mgy$* That makes no sense at all. Force and potential don’t have the same dimensions, so *mgy* can’t be a force. It’s like saying “distance is $vt$ but I am assuming mass is $vt$.” You can’t make arbitrary assumptions. Physics has rules, and dimensional consistency is one of them.

Comment: @Dimitri You are free to study a force that is proportional to $y$ if you would like. The problem I and the other commenters have seems to be one of units (which are important). You should use different symbols other than $m$ and $g$ in your second force, since you have already introduced $m$ and $g$ in terms of gravitational force $mg$, and so $mgy$ does not have units of force. Rather, you should write your second force like $F=-ky$, which is a more-standard notation.

Comment: This question should be removed since its entire premise is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you assume force is $mgy$:

After reading OP's comments, it seems that OP just wants to understand how to solve a problem where the force is proportional to the displacement.

The main problem the commenters (myself included) seem to have is one of units. In particular, OP already said that $m$ and $g$ are the usual mass and gravitational constant. Therefore, $mgy$ can not have units of force.

So, we can introduce another parameter with units of length $\ell$ and write, more appropriately:
$$
F = \frac{mg}{\ell}y\;.
$$

In fact, to save us some writing, let's define:
$$
k\equiv -\frac{mg}{\ell}
$$
and thus we can write:
$$
F = -ky\;.
$$

Such a force has been studied since at least the 17th century. In particular, by Robert Hooke, who famously quipped "ut tensio sic vis." Such a force is often called a *spring force*.

Certainly one can solve the equation:
$$
m\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = -k y\;,
$$
(given appropriate boundary conditions).

The solutions for position $y(t)$ are well-known to be sinusoidal. For example
$$
y(t) = A\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t)\;
$$
is one such solution.